# Is there a way to implement twitter search?

Tags: php, xml, search, twitter

I would like to implement twitter search, but with the use of their API. I think most of you know the search which they have on their home page.

Search gives such link: `http://twitter.com/#search?q=ipod ubuntu`

I looked in API for a possible solution, but didn't find it.
Also it would be nice if the response to the request could be in XML format, since I know that some API methods allow only json or atom.

Hope there is one(**with the use of API**).

Comment: cool you are from talinn, iLike that city!! 
It's true, twitter returns json or atom, but i am sure there are many json2xml scripts out there.

Comment: Yes. I read about one. But to do so I need to work with PEER and as I understand many servers yet don't have that possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at this [twitter search api documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search)?
You can return results in atom or json simply with http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=ipod+ubuntu
or
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=ipod+ubuntu

Isn't atom an xml language? Shouldn't a decent xml parser be able to handle atom?

Comment: But as I said earlier it would be great is they could be in XML and no didn't see it. Thanks for the link.